# get width, height from Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to get width and height of Linear layout, however I do not know when the Relative Layout is ready to provide me these two attributes.

but it only returns 0.

my screen
[image]

please check my code, i have no idea.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        int width = container.getWidth();
        int height = container.getWidth();

        Log.d("MainActivity onCreate", "width #" + width + ", height #" + height);
    }
}
```

and activity_main.xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FFFFFFAA"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you try to get dimensions on `onResume()` or on `onCreate()` method, it always returns `0`. So you should use `ViewTreeObserver`

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = container.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        container.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        finalHeight = container.getMeasuredHeight();
        finalWidth = container.getMeasuredWidth();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Also you can customize your `View` which will extends with `LinearLayout` and in `onMeasure()` method you can get `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all replace

```
 int height = container.getWidth();
```

by

```
 int height = container.getHeight();
```

`container.getHeight()` will return `0` (as well as `container.getWidth()`) if it's not drawed yet.

Solution would be to get the height after your view is layouted:

```
container.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
     int height = container.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are calling getWidth twice - for width and height.
You can try it with measureSpecs, like this:

```
int matchParentMeasureSpecWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) container.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int matchParentMeasureSpecHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((View) container.getParent()).getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
v.measure(matchParentMeasureSpecWidth, matchParentMeasureSpecHeight);

int height = container.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and mesaure it first. But make sure you do so only after every other view as been added beacuse your LinearLayout is depended on other views.

```
LinearLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
LinearLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

            container.post(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Log.i("TEST", "  Layout width : "+ container.getWidth() +"  Layout height "+ container.getHeight()) ;

                }
            });
```